# mismatched input 'TABLE' expecting 'CONNECTOR'. Error code: 40001

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, ksqldb

I am following tutorial from : https://piotrminkowski.com/2022/06/22/introduction-to-ksqldb-on-kubernetes-with-spring-boot/ where we're developing **Spring Boot and ksqldb** example.

KTableCreateListener.java

```
@Component
public class KTableCreateListener implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KTableCreateListener.class);
    private Client ksqlClient;

    public KTableCreateListener(Client ksqlClient) {
        this.ksqlClient = ksqlClient;
    }

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
       try {
          String sql = "CREATE SOURCE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS transactions_view ("
                + "                    id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,"
                + "                    sourceAccountId BIGINT,"
                + "                    targetAccountId BIGINT,"
                + "                    amount INT"
                + "                  ) WITH ("
                + "                    kafka_topic='transactions',"
                + "                    value_format='JSON'"
                + "                  );";
          ExecuteStatementResult result = ksqlClient.executeStatement(sql).get();
          LOG.info("Result: {}", result.queryId().orElse(null));
       } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
          LOG.error("Error: ", e);
       }
    }
}
```

When I am starting the app, I am getting the below error -

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: io.confluent.ksql.api.client.exception.KsqlClientException: Received 400 response from server: line 1:15: mismatched input 'TABLE' expecting 'CONNECTOR'. Error code: 40001
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:395) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1999) ~[na:na]
    at com.example.startup.KTableCreateListener.onApplicationEvent(KTableCreateListener.java:35) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.startup.KTableCreateListener.onApplicationEvent(KTableCreateListener.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:421) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:427) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:378) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:938) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:586) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.DefaultBinderFactory.initializeBinderContextSimple(DefaultBinderFactory.java:471) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.DefaultBinderFactory.getBinderInstance(DefaultBinderFactory.java:265) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.DefaultBinderFactory.doGetBinder(DefaultBinderFactory.java:223) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.DefaultBinderFactory.getBinder(DefaultBinderFactory.java:151) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.getBinder(BindingService.java:386) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.bindProducer(BindingService.java:270) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.bindProducer(BindingService.java:294) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.bindProducer(BindingService.java:298) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.AbstractBindableProxyFactory.createAndBindOutputs(AbstractBindableProxyFactory.java:142) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.OutputBindingLifecycle.doStartWithBindable(OutputBindingLifecycle.java:58) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedValues.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:608) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.AbstractBindingLifecycle.start(AbstractBindingLifecycle.java:57) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.OutputBindingLifecycle.start(OutputBindingLifecycle.java:34) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:356) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:155) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:123) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:935) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:586) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at com.example.SpringBootKsqlExampleApplication.main(SpringBootKsqlExampleApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: io.confluent.ksql.api.client.exception.KsqlClientException: Received 400 response from server: line 1:15: mismatched input 'TABLE' expecting 'CONNECTOR'. Error code: 40001
    at io.confluent.ksql.api.client.impl.ClientImpl.lambda$handleErrorResponse$29(ClientImpl.java:736) ~[ksqldb-api-client-0.26.0.jar:na]
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpClientResponseImpl$BodyHandler.notifyHandler(HttpClientResponseImpl.java:292) ~[vertx-core-3.9.12.jar:3.9.12]
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpClientResponseImpl.lambda$bodyHandler$0(HttpClientResponseImpl.java:193) ~[vertx-core-3.9.12.jar:3.9.12]
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpClientResponseImpl.handleEnd(HttpClientResponseImpl.java:248) ~[vertx-core-3.9.12.jar:3.9.12]
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http2ClientConnection$Http2ClientStream.handleEnd(Http2ClientConnection.java:260) ~[vertx-core-3.9.12.jar:3.9.12]
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.VertxHttp2Stream.lambda$new$1(VertxHttp2Stream.java:68) ~[vertx-core-3.9.12.jar:3.9.12]
    at io.vertx.core.streams.impl.InboundBuffer.handleEvent(InboundBuffer.java:237) ~[vertx-core-3.9.12.jar:3.9.12]
    at io.vertx.core.streams.impl.InboundBuffer.write(InboundBuffer.java:127) ~[vertx-core-3.9.12.jar:3.9.12]
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.VertxHttp2Stream.onEnd(VertxHttp2Stream.java:107) ~[vertx-core-3.9.12.jar:3.9.12]
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.VertxHttp2Stream.onEnd(VertxHttp2Stream.java:100) ~[vertx-core-3.9.12.jar:3.9.12]
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http2ConnectionBase.lambda$onDataRead$10(Http2ConnectionBase.java:323) ~[vertx-core-3.9.12.jar:3.9.12]
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.executeTask(ContextImpl.java:366) ~[vertx-core-3.9.12.jar:3.9.12]
    at io.vertx.core.impl.EventLoopContext.execute(EventLoopContext.java:43) ~[vertx-core-3.9.12.jar:3.9.12]
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.executeFromIO(ContextImpl.java:229) ~[vertx-core-3.9.12.jar:3.9.12]
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.executeFromIO(ContextImpl.java:221) ~[vertx-core-3.9.12.jar:3.9.12]
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http2ConnectionBase.onDataRead(Http2ConnectionBase.java:323) ~[vertx-core-3.9.12.jar:3.9.12]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2FrameListenerDecorator.onDataRead(Http2FrameListenerDecorator.java:36) ~[netty-codec-http2-4.1.78.Final.jar:4.1.78.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2EmptyDataFrameListener.onDataRead(Http2EmptyDataFrameListener.java:49) ~[netty-codec-http2-4.1.78.Final.jar:4.1.78.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2ConnectionDecoder$FrameReadListener.onDataRead(DefaultHttp2ConnectionDecoder.java:307) ~[netty-codec-http2-4.1.78.Final.jar:4.1.78.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2FrameReader.readDataFrame(DefaultHttp2FrameReader.java:415) ~[netty-codec-http2-4.1.78.Final.jar:4.1.78.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2FrameReader.processPayloadState(DefaultHttp2FrameReader.java:250) ~[netty-codec-http2-4.1.78.Final.jar:4.1.78.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2FrameReader.readFrame(DefaultHttp2FrameReader.java:159) ~[netty-codec-http2-4.1.78.Final.jar:4.1.78.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2ConnectionDecoder.decodeFrame(DefaultHttp2ConnectionDecoder.java:173) ~[netty-codec-http2-4.1.78.Final.jar:4.1.78.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DecoratingHttp2ConnectionDecoder.decodeFrame(DecoratingHttp2ConnectionDecoder.java:63) ~[netty-codec-http2-4.1.78.Final.jar:4.1.78.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler$FrameDecoder.decode(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:393) ~[netty-codec-http2-4.1.78.Final.jar:4.1.78.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler.decode(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:453) ~[netty-codec-http2-4.1.78.Final.jar:4.1.78.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:510) ~[netty-codec-4.1.78.Final.jar:4.1.78.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:449) ~[netty-codec-4.1.78.Final.jar:4.1.78.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:279) ~[netty-codec-4.1.78.Final.jar:4.1.78.Final]
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.VertxHttp2ConnectionHandler.channelRead(VertxHttp2ConnectionHandler.java:418) ~[vertx-core-3.9.12.jar:3.9.12]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.78.Final.jar:4.1.78.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.78.Final.jar:4.1.78.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.78.Final.jar:4.1.78.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[netty-transport-4.1.78.Final.jar:4.1.78.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.78.Final.jar:4.1.78.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.78.Final.jar:4.1.78.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[netty-transport-4.1.78.Final.jar:4.1.78.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166) ~[netty-transport-4.1.78.Final.jar:4.1.78.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:722) ~[netty-transport-4.1.78.Final.jar:4.1.78.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:658) ~[netty-transport-4.1.78.Final.jar:4.1.78.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:584) ~[netty-transport-4.1.78.Final.jar:4.1.78.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:496) ~[netty-transport-4.1.78.Final.jar:4.1.78.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) ~[netty-common-4.1.78.Final.jar:4.1.78.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.78.Final.jar:4.1.78.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.78.Final.jar:4.1.78.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest referring to actual ksql docs, not external blogs.

`CREATE SOURCE TABLE` is not correct. It should be `CREATE TABLE`.

The error is saying the parser is expecting `CREATE SOURCE CONNECTOR`.